# How to see all final changes in working branch in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

`Master-->dev--->feature`

I have three branches

```
Master-> main branch 
Dev-> child branch of Master branch
Feature-> child branch of dev
```

I have made a lot of changes and committed to a feature branch. So I want to see all final changes that I have made in the feature branch till now and I need to know how many files I have changed, all about like we can see the current changes in the git option of vs code.

It is simply like I want to compare the code of the feature branch to dev. for this we have the command `git difftool <branch1> <branch2>`

Is there any visual representation of this command in vs code?

Comment: you tried 'git log' command.

Comment: `git log` command displays a record of the commits in a Git repository, I need to know in which file, lines I have changed.

Comment: with `git diff` specify 2 commit hashes

Comment: like `git diff` shows the current changes, it shows files and which lines you have changed. same it is I want to know for all changes I have made till now in the feature branch.

Comment: nope git diff is not working with a hash for me because It shows individual committed and i have changes same file so many times

Comment: means I have made committed to one file too many times.

Comment: I want to compare the code of  feature branch with dev

Comment: okay thanks, I have found this `git difftool` .it helps me so do you know is there any visual representation of this command in vs code like we have visual representation of  `git diff` in vs code.

Comment: *Branch names* have no parent/child relationships. This means `feature` is not a child of `dev`. It's not a child of `master` either. Nor is it a parent or sibling of either `dev` or `master`. It's just a stand-alone name. It selects one particular commit; the commit it selects is, by definition, the last commit on `feature`. Each branch name can be moved to any commit you like and when you do move one, that newly selected commit is now the last commit on that branch. (This isn't related to your question about how to view differences, but is important to keep in mind when using GIt.)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there is a way to see all changes in VS Code that I found out just now. This is a feature of the [GitLens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).

1. In the "Source Control" tab you can find a dropdown that is named "Search & Compare".
2. There you can add a new search by clicking the + and select "Compare References...".
3. Select "Working Tree" and "master".

This will show all changed files in comparison with your *current* state of master (pulling master will update this), which is too much of course. But luckily there's a filter.

4. Select the funnel-icon to filter and select "Show Left-side Files Only"
5. Done!

Now you can see all changed files since the creation of your branch. Tip: you can pin this search by clicking the pin-icon.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Quick note - this is actually a feature of Gitlens extension not native VS Code :)

Comment: hey @Yan is there any way to use indexing when using these features? The files are opened read-only and one cannot make a change. But to be able to use indexing would be neat feature